# Converter imagem para base64 usando VueJS?

Tags: javascript, imagem, vue.js, base64

Tenho um `<input type="file />` no VueJS e quando eu selecionar uma imagem quero que seja convertida em `base64`, pois salvarei as imagens no banco de dados somente em `base64`. Qual seria o método para pegar somente a `String` `base64` que dá origem à imagem?

```
<input @change="uploadImage" type="file" name="photo" accept="image/*">
<img :src="imageSrc" class="image">
```

---

```
uploadImage: function (e) {
  var files = e.target.files
  if (!files[0]) {
    return
  }
  var data = new FormData()
  data.append('media', files[0])
  var reader = new FileReader()
  reader.onload = (e) => {
    this.imageSrc = e.target.result
  }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pega a instância de `new Vue` pela variável `vm`, para ter acesso a `imageSrc`, depois no método `uploadImage`, utilize [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/FileReader) para carregar e mostrar a imagem direto na tag `<img>`. Exemplo:

```js
Vue.config.debug = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.silent = true;

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#editor',
  data: {
    imageSrc: null
  },
  methods: {
    uploadImage: function() {    
      var file = document
        .querySelector('input[type=file]')
        .files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        vm.imageSrc = e.target.result             
      };
      reader.onerror = function(error) {
        alert(error);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);      
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="editor">
  <p>
   <input @change="uploadImage" type="file" name="photo" accept="image/*">
  </p>
  <img :src="imageSrc" class="image">  
</div>
```

<sub>***Referencia:***</sub>

- [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/FileReader)
- [How to convert file to base64 in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280818/how-to-convert-file-to-base64-in-javascript)
- [FileReader.readAsDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer isso assim...

```
<script>
   let image = ''
   export default{
      created(){
          this.getDataUri('urlDaImagem', (dataUri) => {
              image = dataUri
          })
      },
      methods: {
          getDataUri(url, callback){
              let image = new Image()

              image.onload = () => {
                  let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                  canvas.width = this.naturalWidth
                  canvas.height = this.naturalHeight
                  canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0)
                  callback(canvas.toDataUrl('image/png').replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, ''))
                  callback(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'))
              }

              image.src = url
          }
      }
   }

</script>
```